# IllegalArgumentException: column local_filename is not allowed in queries when calling DownloadManager.query()

Tags: android, android-download-manager, illegalargumentexception, download-manager, xiaomi

in my app i'm starting download via DownloadManager:

```
val downloadId: Long = downloadManager.enqueue(dr)
```

If user reopenning application, i'm checking downloading status via:

```
fun isDownloadInProgress(): Boolean {
    val dq: DownloadManager.Query = DownloadManager.Query()
    dq.setFilterById(downloadId)
    val cursor: Cursor? = downloadManager.query(dq)
    if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return false
    }
    val status: Int = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))
    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING || status == DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

With this code I have some crashes in my Crashlytics dash on Xiaomi with 11 and 12 Android versions:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column local_filename is not allowed in queries
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderProxy.java:481)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1219)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1151)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1107)
       at android.app.DownloadManager$Query.runQuery(DownloadManager.java:1506)
       at android.app.DownloadManager.query(DownloadManager.java:1736)
       at android.app.DownloadManager.query(DownloadManager.java:1718)
```

It throw when i call `val cursor: Cursor? = downloadManager.query(dq)` because under the hood `query()` method of `DownloadManager` calls `query(query, UNDERLYING_COLUMNS);` and `UNDERLYING_COLUMS` contains `DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME` column.

This column is deprecated after API 24, but `DownloadManager` is still using this column under the hood.

My questions is:

1. If am i using `DownloadManager` incorrect and there is another way for check download status, can someone suggest how to do this?
2. If is this a bug on Xiaomi ROM, can someone give me the link on issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Also maybe check the comments here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4203

Comment: I'm seeing this on Xiaomi Mix Fold 3 (Android 13)